# SwiftUI & @FetchRequest sortDescriptors on specific data (team in this case)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I have a MessagesView where I can create and delete messages.
As a guide and example I'm using the Xcode Master-Detail App template with CoreData en Cloud-kit enabled and the WWDS video [Using Core Data With CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/202/)

```
struct TeamsManagerView : View {
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Message.team, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
var messages: FetchedResults<Message>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
var viewContext

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                Text(message.text)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }
…
```

Everything is working and I'm able to add and delete messages.
How can I get the messages for a specific team?
The 'Message.team' sortDescriptor shows me all the messages of all teams

This is my Core Data model, by the way
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must insert in your @FetchRequest an predicate to separate the result of your special team. NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", "TeamName") In your case, you could expand the @FetchResult to see your team's messages:

```
@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Message.team, ascending: true)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", "YourSpecialTeam"),
    animation:.default)
var messages: FetchedResults<Message>
```